# How to get last run Datetime of Crawler in Athena?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-athena, amazon-quicksight

I have AWS Glue Crawler which runs twice a day and populates data in Athena.

Quicksight takes data from Athena and shows it in a dashboard.

I am implementing LastDataRefresh (Datetime) to show in a Quicksight dashboard. Is there a way I can get the last crawler run datetime so that I can store it in an Athena table and show in Quicksight ?

Any other suggestions are also welcome.

Comment: I think that the best way to do that is using AWS API https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-crawling.html#aws-glue-api-crawler-crawling-LastCrawlInfo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR Extract the crawler last run time from Glue's CloudWatch logs

Glue sends a series of events to CloudWatch during each crawler run.  Extract and process the "finished running" logs from `/aws-glue/crawlers` log group to get the latest for each crawler.

Logs for a single crawler run:

```
2021-12-15T12:08:54.448+01:00   [7dd..] BENCHMARK : Running Start Crawl for Crawler lorawan_datasets_bucket_crawler
2021-12-15T12:09:12.559+01:00   [7dd..] BENCHMARK : Classification complete, writing results to database jokerman_events_database
2021-12-15T12:09:12.560+01:00   [7dd..] INFO : Crawler configured with SchemaChangePolicy {"UpdateBehavior":"UPDATE_IN_DATABASE","DeleteBehavior":"DEPRECATE_IN_DATABASE"}.
2021-12-15T12:09:27.064+01:00   [7dd..] BENCHMARK : Finished writing to Catalog
2021-12-15T12:12:13.768+01:00   [7dd..] BENCHMARK : Crawler has finished running and is in state READY
```

Extract and process the `BENCHMARK : Crawler has finished running and is in state READY` logs:

```py
import boto3
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def get_last_runs():
  session = boto3.Session(profile_name='sandbox', region_name='us-east-1')
  logs = session.client('logs')

  startTime = startTime = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=14)

  # https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/logs.html#CloudWatchLogs.Client.filter_log_events
  filtered_events = logs.filter_log_events(
      logGroupName="/aws-glue/crawlers",
      # https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/FilterAndPatternSyntax.html#matching-terms-events
      filterPattern="BENCHMARK state READY", # match "BENCHMARK : Crawler has finished running and is in state READY" messages
      startTime=int(startTime.timestamp()*1000)
  )

  completed_runs = [
      {"crawler": m.get("logStreamName"), "timestamp": datetime.fromtimestamp(m.get("timestamp")/1000).isoformat()}
      for m in filtered_events["events"]
  ]

  # rework the list to get a dictionary of the last runs by crawler
  crawlers = set([r['crawler'] for r in completed_runs])
  last_runs = dict()

  for n in crawlers:
    last_runs[n] = max([d["timestamp"] for d in completed_runs if d["crawler"] == n])

  print(last_runs)
```

Output:

```py
{
  'lorawan_datasets_bucket_crawler': '2021-12-15T12:12:13.768000',
  'jokerman_lorawan_events_table_crawler': '2021-12-15T12:12:12.007000'
}
```

Comment: This is great but if I create Lambda function of above code, how to trigger it once crawler has completed running and save this value in some table to access in athena ?

Comment: Easy peasy.  A [CloudWatch Subcription Filter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/Subscriptions.html) can [trigger a lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/SubscriptionFilters.html#LambdaFunctionExample) when a log group receives a log matching a pattern.  You may could squeeze the entire `get crawler timestamp -> persist to Athena -> refresh Quicksight` logic into a single lambda.  Or create a [Step Function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/welcome.html) to orchestrate the tasks.